# wxPython middle align items in sizer

Tags: python, alignment, wxpython

I am dynamically changing the number of wx objects in my GUI. The code is working but the alignment of the objects is not perfect. The static text objects are not middle aligned with the text objects.

[image: misalignment]

Notice that the word 'if' is not perfectly aligned with 'field name'.

Code:

```
import wx


########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.numRows = 0
        self.frame = parent

        #create sizers
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        controlSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.colSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.addButton = wx.Button(self, label="Add")
        self.addButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAddWidget)
        controlSizer.Add(self.addButton, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.removeButton = wx.Button(self, label="Remove")
        self.removeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onRemoveWidget)
        controlSizer.Add(self.removeButton, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.mainSizer.Add(controlSizer, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.colSizer, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onAddWidget(self, event):
        """"""
        self.numRows += 1

        #create the objects
        rowSizer =wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        ifText = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'If')
        fieldBox1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 'Field Name')
        dropDown1 = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=['<', '<=', '=', '>=', '>'])
        fieldBox2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 'Field Name')
        thenText = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Then')
        fieldBox3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, 'Field Name')


        #create a list of all the objects
        objects = [ifText, fieldBox1, dropDown1, fieldBox2, thenText, fieldBox3]

        #add object to row sizer
        for myObject in objects:
            rowSizer.Add(myObject, 0, wx.ALL, 5)    

        #add the objects to the sizer
        self.colSizer.Add(rowSizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.frame.fSizer.Layout()
        self.frame.Fit()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onRemoveWidget(self, event):
        """"""
        if self.colSizer.GetChildren():
            self.colSizer.Hide(self.numRows-1)
            self.colSizer.Remove(self.numRows-1)
            self.numRows -= 1
            self.frame.fSizer.Layout()
            self.frame.Fit()

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Add / Remove Buttons")
        self.fSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.fSizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.fSizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()

del app
```

Please could someone advise on how I can fix this alignment issue.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh! It turns out I just needed to change the alignment when adding items to the row sizer.

```
rowSizer.Add(myObject, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
```